# No software is shown in AppCenter except what is installed

Tags: release-loki

1. AppCenter is empty, only the installed software is shown.
2. I can't add repositories. I get the message 'sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found'.
3. `sudo apt install software-properties-common` doesn't work either. I get the message 'E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common'

Comment: i have the sames problems... i cant install anything and i cant add repos... what i do a operating system if i cant install my apps? no gparted no clementine no steam no chromium no easytag no no no no... the command sudo apt-get update dont solve the problem mate...! now i see here http://blog.elementary.io/post/145881464631/loki-beta
to say no unsafe software source... someone else will decide for me what is safe and what is not..? reminds me microsoft and osx

Comment: Do you have ipv6? It might be the problem.

Comment: Related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-to-open-deb-files-with-appcenter

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18 KDE and the symptoms are the same (some websites don't load, update doens't work). I'm almost certain that it's a network manager and/or ipv6 problem on a pppoe (dsl) connection. In Freya ipv6 is ignored by default. In Loki I'm connecting with ipv6 by default, and I wasn't able to disable it yet with several methods found over the internet.

Comment: So I solved it. I needed to add the line "mtu=1492" in the file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*Connection name* like this:
[ppp] 
lcp-echo-failure=5 
lcp-echo-interval=30 
mtu=1492
After making the DSL connection at first, of course. IPv6 doesn't need to be stopped. Then reboot and updates are working, and software is visible in AppCenter.

Comment: No help in updating softcenter. We sitll have no relevant apps.

Answer (score 3):

I had this too. To fix run `sudo apt update`

Once it's done you can add PPAs after installing `software-common-properties`, although this is not recommended to ensure security and stability.

Comment: sudo apt-get update doesn't work either:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: So I killed all the apt processes and removed /var/lib/apt/lists/lock and /var/cache/apt/archives/lock. sudo apt-get update initiated, but it's very, very slow. After 1 hour and a half it still didn't finish, so I closed it. I was looking for a solution to speed it up, but couldn't find any (Epiphany is not opening all pages).

Comment: Maybe reboot? Sounds like something might be getting held onto by the system and preventing you from moving forward. Otherwise maybe try to reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled and it's the same. It might just be an ipv6 problem, but I'm not sure, because also some websites don't load. I don't know if I properly disabled ipv6.

Answer (score 2):

AppCenter displayed the installed apps only. Running `sudo apt update` did not solve the problem. I had to reinstall AppCenter to fix it.

1. Remove AppCenter:

   `sudo apt purge appcenter`
2. Reboot
3. Install AppCenter:

   `sudo apt install appcenter`
4. Update repositories:

   `sudo apt update`
5. Open AppCenter.

Comment: I also had to resolve any repository related errors which were listed by apt-get udpate. Might be worth adding that to the answer