# "No Results. No apps could be found. Try changing search terms."

Tags: appcenter

This bug appears identical to that described in

[I am unable to update or install software in the AppCenter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/i-am-unable-to-update-or-install-software-in-the-appcenter)

however none of the fixes suggested there (reinstalling packageit, reinstalling appcenter and all the dependencies needed to build it) worked.

Problem started when I accidentally hit "Authenticate" prior to typing my password during a routine upgrade in appcenter, after which it wouldn't let me type in my password any more, so I killed it and tried again, with the above results.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Problem went away after a reboot. Ggggeeeeerrrrrr!