# newby from Mac: how do I "install" a program I've downloaded

Tags: applications, software-installation

sorry that this question is "stupid" : ) So, I've installed elementary, figured out how to access the internet, downloaded two of my favorite programs (LibreOffice and Firefox), clicked on the packages and "extracted" the files. Where did the applications go? and How do I put them in my applications file? Nothing in the extracted files has the names of the applications (that I could find). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most apps are in the AppCenter (the icon with a down arrow). Just open it and use the search function to find the app you want.

I'm not sure what you did but you can delete those files you've downloaded. Both apps, Firefox and Libreoffice are in the AppCenter.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But in AppCenter on my new os, it only shows applications I already have installed. And if I "search" it finds nothing.

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure: If you go to the Categories tab in AppCenter and then you press Audio. Does it show anything besides what you've installed?  

If it doesn't. Open Terminal  and write `sudo apt update`. Press "Paste Anyway" if that window appears. This command is just going to update your sources so all applications appear. If you get any error, reboot and try a second time.

Comment: the sudo apt update worked. I had tried various other terminal commands (and got things like -- doesn't exist, even though the man pages said it did.) After running the command as given, everthing updated, including the appCenter, and I was able to perform a search and install of both programs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you new to Linux? If you are then you should learn how to install software in Linux. Since elementary is derived from Ubuntu then just google how to install bla in Ubuntu. Installing libreoffice and firefox is so easy. You can find them in repository by typing

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

in terminal. Just learn how to use apt and you are master.

Answer (score 1):

Not a stupid question at all! It sounds like two things are going on here:

1. AppCenter isn't working properly. It should list a wide variety of apps, including LibreOffice and Firefox. See [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/no-software-is-shown-in-appcenter-except-what-is-installed) for a fix and [this bug ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1615270) for details on the underlying problem.
2. Ubuntu apps are often distributed outside the AppCenter in .deb packages. elementary OS doesn't come with a way to install .deb packages. This is by design, and in most cases installing an app from the AppCenter is simpler and more reliable than installing the same app from a .deb package. That said, you can install .deb packages by following [these instructions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-can-i-install-deb-files-in-loki).